# Python error when trying to create an AWS stack using a template

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am a python newbie trying to execute an aws cloudformation script via python 2.7.  The script works flawlessly from the aws console and from the command line.  However, when  I try to run from within python I get error "Template format error: JSON not well-formed. (line 1, column 5)"

```
def create_stack(args):
conn = _create_cf_connection(args)
try:
    conn.create_stack(args.stack_name, template_body="file://D://Project/testTemplate.json")   
except boto.exception.BotoServerError, e:
    print e.error_message
```

I have run 'validate-template' and no errors are returned.  Can anyone help me?

here is the json template:

```
{
"AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
"Description": "AWS MiniProject: Create a single EC2 instance with Apache Server.",
"Parameters": {
    "KeyName": {
        "Description": "Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the instance",
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName",
        "Default": "thedigginman",
        "ConstraintDescription": "must be the name of an existing EC2 KeyPair."
    },
    "InstanceType": {
        "Description": "WebServer EC2 instance type",
        "Type": "String",
        "Default": "t2.micro",
        "AllowedValues": [
            "t1.micro",
            "t2.nano",
            "t2.micro",
            "t2.small",
            "t2.medium",
            "t2.large",
            "m1.small",
            "m1.medium",
            "m1.large",
            "m1.xlarge",
            "m2.xlarge",
            "m2.2xlarge",
            "m2.4xlarge",
            "m3.medium",
            "m3.large",
            "m3.xlarge",
            "m3.2xlarge",
            "m4.large",
            "m4.xlarge",
            "m4.2xlarge",
            "m4.4xlarge",
            "m4.10xlarge",
            "c1.medium",
            "c1.xlarge",
            "c3.large",
            "c3.xlarge",
            "c3.2xlarge",
            "c3.4xlarge",
            "c3.8xlarge",
            "c4.large",
            "c4.xlarge",
            "c4.2xlarge",
            "c4.4xlarge",
            "c4.8xlarge",
            "g2.2xlarge",
            "g2.8xlarge",
            "r3.large",
            "r3.xlarge",
            "r3.2xlarge",
            "r3.4xlarge",
            "r3.8xlarge",
            "i2.xlarge",
            "i2.2xlarge",
            "i2.4xlarge",
            "i2.8xlarge",
            "d2.xlarge",
            "d2.2xlarge",
            "d2.4xlarge",
            "d2.8xlarge",
            "hi1.4xlarge",
            "hs1.8xlarge",
            "cr1.8xlarge",
            "cc2.8xlarge",
            "cg1.4xlarge"
        ],
        "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid EC2 instance type."
    },
    "SSHLocation": {
        "Description": " The IP address range that can be used to SSH to the EC2 instances",
        "Type": "String",
        "MinLength": "9",
        "MaxLength": "18",
        "Default": "0.0.0.0/0",
        "AllowedPattern": "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})",
        "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x."
    }
},
"Mappings": {
    "AWSInstanceType2Arch": {
        "t1.micro": {
            "Arch": "PV64"
        },
        "t2.nano": {
            "Arch": "HVM64"
        },
        "t2.micro": {
            "Arch": "HVM64"
        },
        "t2.small": {
            "Arch": "HVM64"
        },
        "t2.medium": {
            "Arch": "HVM64"
        },
        "t2.large": {
            "Arch": "HVM64"
        },
        "m1.small": {
            "Arch": "PV64"
        },
        "m1.medium": {
            "Arch": "PV64"
        },
        "m1.large": {
            "Arch": "PV64"
        },
        "m1.xlarge": {
            "Arch": "PV64"
        },
        "m2.xlarge": {
            "Arch": "PV64"
        },
        "m2.2xlarge": {
            "Arch": "PV64"
        },
        "m2.4xlarge": {
            "Arch": "PV64"
        },
        "m3.medium": {
            "Arch": "HVM64"
        },
        "m3.large": {
            "Arch": "HVM64"
        },
        "m3.xlarge": {
            "Arch": "HVM64"
        },
        "m3.2xlarge": {
            "Arch": "HVM64"
        },
        "m4.large": {
            "Arch": "HVM64"
        },
        "m4.xlarge": {
            "Arch": "HVM64"
        },
        "m4.2xlarge": {
            "Arch": "HVM64"
        },
        "m4.4xlarge": {
            "Arch": "HVM64"
        },
        "m4.10xlarge": {
            "Arch": "HVM64"
        },
        "c1.medium": {
            "Arch": "PV64"
        },
        "c1.xlarge": {
            "Arch": "PV64"
        },
        "c3.large": {
            "Arch": "HVM64"
        },
        "c3.xlarge": {
            "Arch": "HVM64"
        },
        "c3.2xlarge": {
            "Arch": "HVM64"
        },
        "c3.4xlarge": {
            "Arch": "HVM64"
        },
        "c3.8xlarge": {
            "Arch": "HVM64"
        },
        "c4.large": {
            "Arch": "HVM64"
        },
        "c4.xlarge": {
            "Arch": "HVM64"
        },
        "c4.2xlarge": {
            "Arch": "HVM64"
        },
        "c4.4xlarge": {
            "Arch": "HVM64"
        },
        "c4.8xlarge": {
            "Arch": "HVM64"
        },
        "g2.2xlarge": {
            "Arch": "HVMG2"
        },
        "g2.8xlarge": {
            "Arch": "HVMG2"
        },
        "r3.large": {
            "Arch": "HVM64"
        },
        "r3.xlarge": {
            "Arch": "HVM64"
        },
        "r3.2xlarge": {
            "Arch": "HVM64"
        },
        "r3.4xlarge": {
            "Arch": "HVM64"
        },
        "r3.8xlarge": {
            "Arch": "HVM64"
        },
        "i2.xlarge": {
            "Arch": "HVM64"
        },
        "i2.2xlarge": {
            "Arch": "HVM64"
        },
        "i2.4xlarge": {
            "Arch": "HVM64"
        },
        "i2.8xlarge": {
            "Arch": "HVM64"
        },
        "d2.xlarge": {
            "Arch": "HVM64"
        },
        "d2.2xlarge": {
            "Arch": "HVM64"
        },
        "d2.4xlarge": {
            "Arch": "HVM64"
        },
        "d2.8xlarge": {
            "Arch": "HVM64"
        },
        "hi1.4xlarge": {
            "Arch": "HVM64"
        },
        "hs1.8xlarge": {
            "Arch": "HVM64"
        },
        "cr1.8xlarge": {
            "Arch": "HVM64"
        },
        "cc2.8xlarge": {
            "Arch": "HVM64"
        }
    },
    "AWSInstanceType2NATArch": {
        "t1.micro": {
            "Arch": "NATPV64"
        },
        "t2.nano": {
            "Arch": "NATHVM64"
        },
        "t2.micro": {
            "Arch": "NATHVM64"
        },
        "t2.small": {
            "Arch": "NATHVM64"
        },
        "t2.medium": {
            "Arch": "NATHVM64"
        },
        "t2.large": {
            "Arch": "NATHVM64"
        },
        "m1.small": {
            "Arch": "NATPV64"
        },
        "m1.medium": {
            "Arch": "NATPV64"
        },
        "m1.large": {
            "Arch": "NATPV64"
        },
        "m1.xlarge": {
            "Arch": "NATPV64"
        },
        "m2.xlarge": {
            "Arch": "NATPV64"
        },
        "m2.2xlarge": {
            "Arch": "NATPV64"
        },
        "m2.4xlarge": {
            "Arch": "NATPV64"
        },
        "m3.medium": {
            "Arch": "NATHVM64"
        },
        "m3.large": {
            "Arch": "NATHVM64"
        },
        "m3.xlarge": {
            "Arch": "NATHVM64"
        },
        "m3.2xlarge": {
            "Arch": "NATHVM64"
        },
        "m4.large": {
            "Arch": "NATHVM64"
        },
        "m4.xlarge": {
            "Arch": "NATHVM64"
        },
        "m4.2xlarge": {
            "Arch": "NATHVM64"
        },
        "m4.4xlarge": {
            "Arch": "NATHVM64"
        },
        "m4.10xlarge": {
            "Arch": "NATHVM64"
        },
        "c1.medium": {
            "Arch": "NATPV64"
        },
        "c1.xlarge": {
            "Arch": "NATPV64"
        },
        "c3.large": {
            "Arch": "NATHVM64"
        },
        "c3.xlarge": {
            "Arch": "NATHVM64"
        },
        "c3.2xlarge": {
            "Arch": "NATHVM64"
        },
        "c3.4xlarge": {
            "Arch": "NATHVM64"
        },
        "c3.8xlarge": {
            "Arch": "NATHVM64"
        },
        "c4.large": {
            "Arch": "NATHVM64"
        },
        "c4.xlarge": {
            "Arch": "NATHVM64"
        },
        "c4.2xlarge": {
            "Arch": "NATHVM64"
        },
        "c4.4xlarge": {
            "Arch": "NATHVM64"
        },
        "c4.8xlarge": {
            "Arch": "NATHVM64"
        },
        "g2.2xlarge": {
            "Arch": "NATHVMG2"
        },
        "g2.8xlarge": {
            "Arch": "NATHVMG2"
        },
        "r3.large": {
            "Arch": "NATHVM64"
        },
        "r3.xlarge": {
            "Arch": "NATHVM64"
        },
        "r3.2xlarge": {
            "Arch": "NATHVM64"
        },
        "r3.4xlarge": {
            "Arch": "NATHVM64"
        },
        "r3.8xlarge": {
            "Arch": "NATHVM64"
        },
        "i2.xlarge": {
            "Arch": "NATHVM64"
        },
        "i2.2xlarge": {
            "Arch": "NATHVM64"
        },
        "i2.4xlarge": {
            "Arch": "NATHVM64"
        },
        "i2.8xlarge": {
            "Arch": "NATHVM64"
        },
        "d2.xlarge": {
            "Arch": "NATHVM64"
        },
        "d2.2xlarge": {
            "Arch": "NATHVM64"
        },
        "d2.4xlarge": {
            "Arch": "NATHVM64"
        },
        "d2.8xlarge": {
            "Arch": "NATHVM64"
        },
        "hi1.4xlarge": {
            "Arch": "NATHVM64"
        },
        "hs1.8xlarge": {
            "Arch": "NATHVM64"
        },
        "cr1.8xlarge": {
            "Arch": "NATHVM64"
        },
        "cc2.8xlarge": {
            "Arch": "NATHVM64"
        }
    },
    "AWSRegionArch2AMI": {
        "us-east-1": {
            "PV64": "ami-8ff710e2",
            "HVM64": "ami-f5f41398",
            "HVMG2": "ami-4afd1d27"
        },
        "us-west-2": {
            "PV64": "ami-eff1028f",
            "HVM64": "ami-d0f506b0",
            "HVMG2": "ami-ee897b8e"
        },
        "us-west-1": {
            "PV64": "ami-ac85fbcc",
            "HVM64": "ami-6e84fa0e",
            "HVMG2": "ami-69106909"
        },
        "eu-west-1": {
            "PV64": "ami-23ab2250",
            "HVM64": "ami-b0ac25c3",
            "HVMG2": "ami-936de5e0"
        },
        "eu-central-1": {
            "PV64": "ami-27c12348",
            "HVM64": "ami-d3c022bc",
            "HVMG2": "ami-8e7092e1"
        },
        "ap-northeast-1": {
            "PV64": "ami-26160d48",
            "HVM64": "ami-29160d47",
            "HVMG2": "ami-91809aff"
        },
        "ap-northeast-2": {
            "PV64": "NOT_SUPPORTED",
            "HVM64": "ami-cf32faa1",
            "HVMG2": "NOT_SUPPORTED"
        },
        "ap-southeast-1": {
            "PV64": "ami-f3dd0a90",
            "HVM64": "ami-1ddc0b7e",
            "HVMG2": "ami-3c30e75f"
        },
        "ap-southeast-2": {
            "PV64": "ami-8f94b9ec",
            "HVM64": "ami-0c95b86f",
            "HVMG2": "ami-543d1137"
        },
        "sa-east-1": {
            "PV64": "ami-e188018d",
            "HVM64": "ami-fb890097",
            "HVMG2": "NOT_SUPPORTED"
        },
        "cn-north-1": {
            "PV64": "ami-77a46e1a",
            "HVM64": "ami-05a66c68",
            "HVMG2": "NOT_SUPPORTED"
        }
    }
},
"Resources": {
    "WebServerInstance": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
        "Metadata": {
            "AWS::CloudFormation::Init": {
                "configSets": {
                    "InstallAndRun": [
                        "Install"
                    ]
                },
                "Install": {
                    "packages": {
                        "yum": {
                            "httpd": []
                        }
                    },
                    "files": {
                        "/var/www/html/index.html": {
                            "content": {
                                "Fn::Join": [
                                    "",
                                    [
                                        "<html>\n",
                                        "  <head>\n",
                                        "    <title>Stelligent Mini Project</title>\n",
                                        "    <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\">\n",
                                        "  </head>\n",
                                        "  <body>\n",
                                        "    <h1>Automation for the People!</h1>\n",
                                        "  </body>\n",
                                        "</html>\n"
                                    ]
                                ]
                            },
                            "mode": "000600",
                            "owner": "apache",
                            "group": "apache"
                        },
                        "/etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf": {
                            "content": {
                                "Fn::Join": [
                                    "",
                                    [
                                        "[main]\n",
                                        "stack=",
                                        {
                                            "Ref": "AWS::StackId"
                                        },
                                        "\n",
                                        "region=",
                                        {
                                            "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                                        },
                                        "\n"
                                    ]
                                ]
                            },
                            "mode": "000400",
                            "owner": "root",
                            "group": "root"
                        },
                        "/etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf": {
                            "content": {
                                "Fn::Join": [
                                    "",
                                    [
                                        "[cfn-auto-reloader-hook]\n",
                                        "triggers=post.update\n",
                                        "path=Resources.WebServerInstance.Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init\n",
                                        "action=/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v ",
                                        "         --stack ",
                                        {
                                            "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
                                        },
                                        "         --resource WebServerInstance ",
                                        "         --configsets InstallAndRun ",
                                        "         --region ",
                                        {
                                            "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                                        },
                                        "\n",
                                        "runas=root\n"
                                    ]
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "services": {
                        "sysvinit": {
                            "httpd": {
                                "enabled": "true",
                                "ensureRunning": "true"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "Properties": {
            "ImageId": {
                "Fn::FindInMap": [
                    "AWSRegionArch2AMI",
                    {
                        "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                    },
                    {
                        "Fn::FindInMap": [
                            "AWSInstanceType2Arch",
                            {
                                "Ref": "InstanceType"
                            },
                            "Arch"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "InstanceType": {
                "Ref": "InstanceType"
            },
            "SecurityGroups": [
                {
                    "Ref": "WebServerSecurityGroup"
                }
            ],
            "KeyName": {
                "Ref": "KeyName"
            },
            "UserData": {
                "Fn::Base64": {
                    "Fn::Join": [
                        "",
                        [
                            "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
                            "yum update -y\n",
                            "#yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap\n",
                            "# Install the files and packages from the metadata\n",
                            "# The cfn-init helper script reads template metadata from\n",
                            "# the AWS::CloudFormation::Init key and acts accordingly to:\n",
                            "#     Fetch and parse metadata from CloudFormation\n",
                            "#     Install packages\n",
                            "#     Write files to disk\n",
                            "#     Enable/disable and start/stop services\n",
                            "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v ",
                            "         --stack ",
                            {
                                "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
                            },
                            "         --resource WebServerInstance ",
                            "         --configsets InstallAndRun ",
                            "         --region ",
                            {
                                "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                            },
                            "\n",
                            "# Signal the status from cfn-init\n",
                            "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? ",
                            "         --stack ",
                            {
                                "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
                            },
                            "         --resource WebServerInstance ",
                            "         --region ",
                            {
                                "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                            },
                            "\n"
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "CreationPolicy": {
            "ResourceSignal": {
                "Timeout": "PT5M"
            }
        }
    },
    "WebServerSecurityGroup": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
        "Properties": {
            "GroupDescription": "Enable HTTP access via port 80",
            "SecurityGroupIngress": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "FromPort": "80",
                    "ToPort": "80",
                    "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                },
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "FromPort": "22",
                    "ToPort": "22",
                    "CidrIp": {
                        "Ref": "SSHLocation"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
},
"Outputs": {
    "WebsiteURL": {
        "Description": "URL for newly created MiniProject server",
        "Value": {
            "Fn::Join": [
                "",
                [
                    "http://",
                    {
                        "Fn::GetAtt": [
                            "WebServerInstance",
                            "PublicDnsName"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hm, maybe provide the JSON file here in a nicely formated code block, or wait: does this path you enter as value to the template_body key work on AWS? Thanks.

Comment: yes, I use this same file when executing from the aws console.  It also works if I execute from the command line

Comment: @Dilettant:  I added the JSON file.

Comment: Two ideas: 1) as I said the string you enter as filepath: does the way you invoke the script when it fails to parse the json look at the content of the file or does it expect the json to be in the string, in the latter case line 1 column 5 would be the colon which would be indeed the first invalid character in a json text (allowing top level texts) as it does err on well-formedness and not model error 2) if it looks into the right file, does it have encoding issues in that way invoked, like windows code page or line endings? HTH

Comment: Thanks for adding, could you edit once more (to inlcude the closing curly brace in the code block and ensure, that in your file you do not miss the opening first curly brace, as I do not see it in the question. Thanks.

Comment: @Dilettant: I updated the JSON file.  Running it through a JSON validator shows no errors.  I also tried saving the file as UNIX/UTF-8, but still no difference.

Comment: Have you tried a json.load on the file?  I find that sometimes the default Python json parser can choke on json strings that work with say a JS provider.

Comment: Hi @JLPeyret.  Sorry, but I don't know what you mean by json.load?

Comment: @JLPeyret:  I looked up documentation for _json.load_ and implemented in my code but still had no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`template_body` expects a string.  Try `template_url` instead or use some other code to load the file on the local disk into a string

See http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/cloudformation.html

Comment: thanks @Vorsprung!  It worked with `template_url` with no problems.  Finally got it working using `template_body` by reading the file into a string.  Thanks!